# Eclipse "saving server item information"

Tags: eclipse, maven, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse with team foundation server. While saving a file or building the project "Saving server item information"  operation automatically starts in background and makes all other process in waiting state.

What can be done to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi cks, any update on this, have your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

If the "Saving server item information" always operate ,this maybe  a network problem. To narrow down the issue first check if you can use any TFS features from the plug-in (is "Refresh Server Item Information" the only thing that fails)?  If you can't use any TFS features from the plug-in, check that Eclipse's HTTP proxy configuration is correct.

> If you can use some TFS features, but the server item information
>   refresh feature is failing, check that you don't have an HTTP proxy,
>   firewall, or NAT device between your client and TFS that is dropping
>   TCP sockets after a short time.
>
> Refreshing/saving information for a large number of files, or from a
>   heavily loaded server, may take a while (perhaps minutes).  A network
>   device that "drops" the active TCP socket without notifying the client
>   would also cause this behavior.

Beside, also recommend that you try the [latest TEE release](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) if above is not work.